# R: Wrap parts of environment with carrier::crate for prediction of new data

Tags: r, deployment, predict, mlr

I want to deploy a machine learning model that was created using mlr. Therefor I tried wrapping the learned model's predictor applying carrier::crate() function:

```
predictor <- carrier::crate(
                  function(data){
                      predict(object = model,
                              newdata = data)},
                   model = model)
```

In general this seems to work, however when I execute the code on the target environmet, which does not have installed mlr, I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict"): no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "WrappedModel"
```

After some investigations I found out that in the learning environment with mlr the class of predict() is

```
class(predict)
# [1] "nonstandardGenericFunction"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "methods"
```

whereas in the predicting environment without mlr it is

```
class(predictor)
# [1] "function"
```

So mlr appears to change the predict fucntion in a way that I do not understand yet.

Is there a way to carry the "mlr adjusted" predict function with from the current environment to another one? In the end something like this (which doesn't work) would help me

```
    predictor <- carrier::crate(
                  function(data){
                        my_predict(data) -> p
                        return(p)},
                   model = model,
                   my_predict(data) = predict(object = model, newdata = data))
```

Comment: Have you tried simply deploying the model object itself?

Comment: Yes I did, but the issue remains. Without having loaded mlr package into the environment the predict function doesn't take wrapped models as returned by mlr learning tasks.

Comment: Could you simply load the package?

Comment: This would put additional overhead to the pipeline the prediction is part of. Thus, this is currently regarded as least favorable solution.

Comment: Hmm, did you measure the overhead? Loading the entire encapsulated environment has its overheads too and I'm not convinced that it would be cheaper. Looking at the carrier documentation, it seems that it assumes objects packaged using crate behave in a certain way that I'm not sure applies to mlr models.

Comment: The deployment shall be done on databricks. The drawback would be that either the cluster the scoring is done on cannot be chosen as auto cluster since it needs to be initialized by a custom docker image, or mlr (which comes with multiple dependencies) needs to be installed from the notebook.